# Submit button in bootstrap not submitting the values

Tags: forms, form-submit, submit-button

```
<form name="form1" class="newsletter relative color_default button_in_input" action="process.php" method="post">
```

Hi trying to submit this form but its not doing anything at all. just stays there all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the form and ensure that the submit button is within the `<form></form>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form name="form1" class="newsletter relative color_default button_in_input" action="process.php" method="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Set type of submit button to submit but if you show your code then we can check error.